# Numba jitting changes result when adding certain kind of 0 to local variable

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba, collatz

Consider the following function for calculating the number of steps for a given input to the 3 *n* + 1 problem:

```
def num_steps(b, steps):
    e = b
    d = 0
    while True:
        if e == 1:
            d += steps[e]
            return d
        if e % 2 == 0:
            e //= 2
        else:
            e = 3*e + 1
        d += 1
```

Here, `steps` exists to allow for memoization of the result, but for the sake of this question, we just note that as long as `steps[1] == 0`, it should have no effect, since in that case, the effect of `d += steps[e]` is to add 0 to `d`. Indeed, the following example gives the expected result:

```
import numpy as np

steps = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
print(num_steps(3, steps))  # Prints 7
```

If, however, we JIT compile the method using `numba.jit` (or `njit`), we no longer get the right result:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

steps = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
print(jit(num_steps)(3, steps))  # Prints 0
```

If we remove the seemingly-redundant `d += steps[e]` before compiling the method, we do get the right result, though. We could even put in a `print(steps[e])` prior to `d += steps[e]` and see that the value is 0. I can also move the `d += 1` to the top of the loop (and initialize `d = -1` instead) to get something that also works in the Numba case.

This happens with Numba 0.48.0 (llvmlite 0.31.0) on Python 3.8 (the most recent versions available through the standard conda channel).

Comment: @MrFuppes: Thanks, if I pin Python version to 3.7 with conda (which downgrades Numba to 0.47.0), I still run into the same issue.

Comment: sorry, didn't check my numba version before I wrote the initial comment - can reproduce the invalid result also with Python 3.7 (numba 0.48, llvmlite 0.31)! *However*, if I switch to numba 0.46 / llvmlite 0.30 on Python 3.7, the njitted code works fine.

Comment: @MrFuppes: Thanks, I can confirm that downgrading to numba 0.46 / llvmlite 0.30 resolves the issue.

Comment: [GitHub issue for reference](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5273).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug to me, something with the in-place increment with `steps[e]`. If you set `parallel=True` that's where Numba crashes. You could create an issue at the Numba github repo, perhaps the developers can explain it.

If I rewrite the function to avoid that final in-place increment it works for me:

```
@numba.njit
def numb_steps(b, steps):

    e = b    
    d = 0

    while True:

        if e == 1:
            return d + steps[e]

        if e % 2 == 0:
            e //= 2
        else:
            e = 3*e + 1

        d += 1
```

With:

```
python                    3.7.6
numba                     0.47.0
```